# Problem setting Value for UILabel (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel

I'm reasonably new at the iPhone SDK, so please forgive me if this answer's ridiculously obvious.

I have a ViewController connected to a .xib file (they are called FirstViewController)

I also have a custom class called MyCustomClass. In this class, I have a method like this:

```
- (void)setTheText {
    [myLabel setText:@"foo"];
}
```

I want to call this method to set the text in a label in FirstViewController.xib

So far, I have done this:

Dragged in an "Object" into Interface Builder, and set the class to: MyCustomClass
Connected up the IBOutlet 'myLabel' from MyCustomClass to a UILabel in the view.

However, when I run the program, and press the button to set the label (which is in FirstViewController.m), something like:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {
   MyCustomClass *customClass = [MyCustomClass alloc] init];
   [customClass setTheText];
}
```

This doesn't set though. `NSLog(@"%@",[myLabel text]);` returns (null)

Xcode shows no errors or warnings, what could be wrong?

Thanks,

Michael

Additional Info:

Interface to MyCustomClass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject {
    UILabel *myLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

- (void)setTheText;

@end
```

Comment: Can you post the interface for MyCustomClass? How you do you have myLabel defined in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance of customClass here is completely unrelated to the NIB. You've instantiated a new object using +alloc. If you want to modify the specific MyCustomClass in your NIB, then FirstViewController needs an IBOutlet that points to it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to create a new instance of your custom class in your action method.

There are a couple of ways to do what you want.

**Option 1** is to give your view controller a reference to your custom object. To do this, create an outlet of type `MyCustomClass *` in your view controller, connect that outlet to the new object that you created in your XIB file, and then get rid of the allocation in your action method:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {       
    [customClass setTheText];
}
```

**Option 2** is to let your `CustomClass` handle both the label *and* the action method. To do this, you can simplify things even further. Put an outlet for the `UILabel` into your `CustomClass`, and then simply convert your `setTheText` method into an action:

```
- (IBAction)setTheText:(id)sender {
    [myLabel setText:@"foo"];
}
```

Now, connect that action up to your button, and everything should work like a charm.

**Note:** You should probably use a method name that does not start with "set", since those are commonly used for property setters as part of Cocoa's KVC/KVO system. Instead, I would call it something like `changeLabel`, or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

UILabel also have a property called text to set the value, you might find that easier.

```
myObject.myLabel.text = @"Your text";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am aware of the dot syntax, but I have a 'thing' against it =P, prefer the good old square brackets!

Comment: Gotcha, it's more of a convenience for people who are used to other languages anyway.

Answer (score 0):

well you called your label two things, first a non-ibaction then an ibaction in the property.