# iOS - Unable to set text of UILabel

Tags: ipad, ios, text, uilabel

Ok let me explain the situation, I have two view controller let's call them first and second.

- FirstViewController inherit from UITableViewController
- SecondViewController inherit From UIViewController

The interface for the SecondViewController is made with Interface Builder and contains a label and an UIProgressView. Both label and UIProgressView outlet are connected with the right files owner (SecondViewController).

a little bit of code, In FirstViewController :

the following method is triggered by a notification

```
- (void) addTransfer:(NSNotification *)notification{
        
      NSLog(@"notification received");
      NSDictionary *transferInfo = [notification userInfo];
      // I think the problem is here 
      aTransfer = [[DbTransfer alloc] initWithNibName:@"DbTransfer" bundle:nil];
      //
      aTransfer.srcPath = [transferInfo objectForKey:@"srcPath"];
      aTransfer.dstPath = [transferInfo objectForKey:@"dstPath"];
      [aTransfer startTransfer];
      [transfer addObject:aTransfer];
      [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

those are the tableView dataSource methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
   return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                      numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section   
{
   NSLog(@"%d numberOfRowsInSection",[transfer count]);
   return [transfer count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                               cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell.contentView addSubview:[[transfer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] view]];
return cell;

}
```

this is the code of SecondViewController.h

```
@interface DbTransfer : UIViewController <DBRestClientDelegate> {

IBOutlet UILabel *fileNameLabel;
IBOutlet UIProgressView *transferProgress;

NSString *srcPath;
NSString *dstPath;

DBRestClient *restClient;


}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *fileNameLabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *transferProgress;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *srcPath;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *dstPath;

- (void) startTransfer;

@end
```

this is a method inside SecondViewcontroller.m

```
- (void) startTransfer{
//NSLog(@"%@\n%@",srcPath,dstPath);

if (!fileNameLabel) {
    NSLog(@"null");
}
[self.fileNameLabel setText:[srcPath lastPathComponent]];
//self.fileNameLabel.text=@"test";


NSLog(@"%@",fileNameLabel.text);


restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
restClient.delegate=self;

[restClient loadFile:srcPath intoPath:dstPath];

}
```

as you can see inside the startTransfer I check if fileNameLabel is null and it is, and I don't understand why. Maybe the null value is related to the allocation of the iVar aTransfer. btw it's impossible to set the text of the label.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem was in the initialization, i was setting the label before the view was loaded. Initialize the label in viewDidLoad solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Elio

Simple test - set a breakpoint at the line where you set self.fileNameLabel.text.  When the app stops there, use the debugger to see if the pointer is null.

Most likely causes:
- The outlet is not linked properly
- The file owner is not of the right class, make sure to set it to your DbTransfer class

H

Comment: ok I'm not very good using the debugger but the value 0x0 I think is null, the outlet as I've said at the beggining of my question is set properly, the file owner is DbTransfer. I think the problem is in the way I create each istance of the DbTransfer class. I'Ve read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112588/problem-setting-value-for-uilabel-iphone-sdk) but to be honest I didn't understand the answer.

Comment: You are correct: 0x0 means null, means the UILabel is not linked, which is why the update is not working.  So the problem is definitely in the line you think "aTransfer = [[DbTransfer alloc] initWithNibName:@"DbTransfer" bundle:nil];".  Check: The xib file is included in the target, the xib is called "DbTransfer.xib", aTrasnfer is of tyoe DbTransfer, a pointer and is retained somewhere.

Comment: Yes the problem is there, I "solved" the this issue changing the point in wich the text attributes of the label was set. Basically I was trying to set the text before the view was loaded, with ,obviously no effect on the label, so now I set the text on the label in the viewDidLoad method. Anyway even if this changing "partially" solved my problem I think something wrong is going on.

Comment: I said partially because, now I'm facing another issue that I think is related. When I delete a row from the table (suppose the table has only a row, so now it's empty) and I create a new instance of DbTransfer and insert it into the table, the old label is still visible below the new label. that's all for now... anyway thanks for your help (and sorry for my english)

Comment: Thanks for this awesome tip! It helped me see that the problem didn't lie at all where I thought it did!