# UITableViewController isn't passing data

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I was trying to pass data between an UITableViewController which is showed with:

```
SeleccionBundesligaViewController *seleccionBundesligaVC = [[SeleccionBundesligaViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

seleccionBundesligaVC.title = @"1.Bundesliga";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:seleccionBundesligaVC animated:YES];
```

and when I select a row it's closed by:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dic = [equipos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    InformacionPartidaViewController *infoPartidaVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"infoPartidaVC"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [infoPartidaVC.labelNombreEquipo setText:[dic objectForKey:@"nombre"]];

}
```

But when I select the row, it doesn't pass data to 'infoPartidaVC'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a property in your SeleccionBundesligaViewController's .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) InformacionPartidaViewController *infoPartidaVC;
```

When you create your UITableViewController and before you push it, add the reference:

```
SeleccionBundesligaViewController *seleccionBundesligaVC = [[SeleccionBundesligaViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

seleccionBundesligaVC.title = @"1.Bundesliga";
seleccionBundesligaVC.infoPartidaVC = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:seleccionBundesligaVC animated:YES];
```

Then, in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath in your UITableViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dic = [equipos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.infoPartidaVC.labelNombreEquipo setText:[dic objectForKey:@"nombre"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are setting the text of the label before the label is shown.
have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051210/ios-unable-to-set-text-of-uilabel/5079780#5079780) asked answered by me

Comment: And how can I initialize it?

Comment: create an NSString property on the infoPartidaVC set is value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, in viewDidLoad of infoPartidaVC set the label using the string